# Scala recursion depth differences and StackOverflowError below allowed depth

Tags: scala, recursion, jvm, stack-overflow

The following program was written to check how deep recursion in Scala can go deep on my machine. I assume that it mostly depends on stack's size assigned to this program. However, after calculating the maximal depth of recursion (catching exception when it appears) and trying to simulate a recursion of this depth I got odd outputs.

```
object RecursionTest {

  def sumArrayRec(elems: Array[Int]) = {

    def goFrom(i: Int, size: Int, elms: Array[Int]): Int = {
      if (i < size) elms(i) + goFrom(i + 1, size, elms)
      else 0
    }
    goFrom(0, elems.length, elems)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val recDepth = recurseTest(0, 0, Array(1))
    println("sumArrayRec = " + sumArrayRec((0 until recDepth).toArray))
  }

  def recurseTest(i: Int, j: Int, arr: Array[Int]): Int = {
    try {
      recurseTest(i + 1, j + 1, arr)
    } catch { case e: java.lang.StackOverflowError =>
      println("Recursion depth on this system is " + i + ".")
      i
    }
  }

}
```

The results vary among executions of the program.

One of them is a desirable output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

Recursion depth on this system is 7166.
sumArrayRec = 25672195

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Nevertheless, the second possible output which I get indicates an error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

Recursion depth on this system is 8129.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at RecursionTest$.goFrom$1(lab44.scala:6)
    at RecursionTest$.goFrom$1(lab44.scala:6)
    at RecursionTest$.goFrom$1(lab44.scala:6)
    (...)
    at RecursionTest$.goFrom$1(lab44.scala:6)
    at RecursionTest$.goFrom$1(lab44.scala:6)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I didn't observe any dependence or relationship of them, I just once got the first, and other time the second

All of that lead me to the following questions:

1. Why do I get an error and what causes it?
2. Is this the stack overflow error and if yes...
3. Why the size of stack changes in the same time when the program is running? Is it even possible?

When I changed `println("sumArrayRec = " + sumArrayRec((0 until recDepth).toArray))` into 
`println("sumArrayRec = " + sumArrayRec((0 until recDepth - 5000).toArray))`, so much less, the behaviour remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You get a stack overflow because you cause a stack overflow
2. Yes
3. The max stack doesn't change, the JVM sets this. Your two methods `recurseTest` and `sumArrayRec` push different amounts to the stack. `recurseTest` is *basically* adding 2 ints the stack with each call while `sumArrayRec` is adding 3 ints since you have a call to `elms(i)`, probably more with addition/ifelse (more instructions). It's tough to tell since the JVM is handling all of this and it's purpose is to obscure this from what you need to know. Also, who knows what optimizations the JVM is doing behind the scenes which can drastically effect the stack sizes created from each method call. On multiple runs you'll get different depths for stack due to system timing etc, maybe the jvm will optimize in the short time the program has run, maybe it won't, it's non-deterministic in this scenario. If you ran some warmup code before hand that might make your tests more deterministic so any optimizations will or will not take place.

You should look into using something like [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for your tests, it will help with the determinism.

Side note: you can also manually change your stack size with `-Xss2M`, common for SBT usage.

Comment: Why did you say that recurseTest pushes only two parameters, as it receives three parameters?

Comment: so it creates 2 new ints, 2 ints are sent to it, and one pointer, so you have about 5 ints on the stack excluding instructions, the array might get optimized away since it's unused. Really you can't tell unless you look at the generated assembly, `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly`, but JVM optimizations might change these at runtime